# Socket disconnected after not receving data

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I want to build a connection between a RPI and my computer (Python code) so they can communicate. I use socket method for this. The thing is that I need my computer to look if nay data as been send by the RPi. The second I use .recv() and there's no data to read, the RPi get disconnected. So when a few second later I try again, well the code enter an infinite loop, because there's no more connection with the RPi.

I try several methods, but I can't get it to work. If someone has any idea, I would appreciate it. I tried to understand non-blocking socket and select() method, but I'm not sure it helps me out...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Unless you set the socket non-blocking, `recv` will block until data is available (or the socket is forced to close).  We can't really advise you unless you show us the code you're using.

Comment: `recv()` normally blocks until there's data to receive, unless you put the socket into non-blocking mode. If it's returning no data, that means the RPi closed the connection. You need to loop and keep accepting the connection.

Comment: In order to loop and keeping accepting the RPi, I need the RPi to keep asking permission to connect? Not that conviniant. Do you know another function than recv() that might be more helpfull?

Comment: @vmon Please show us the code you are using for sockets on both machines.